# Shields.io hardcode download count badge

Tags: shields.io

Shields seems quite powerful and from [this](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/how-to-make-custom-language-badges-for-your-profile-using-shields-io-d2aeaf016b6b) tutorial I have a sense I could just design a custom badge. Because my download count for my app is coming from multiple websites I don't think I can get a proper estimate so I want to hardcode it in.

How can I make a badge that looks like the download count badge from shields.io but allows me to enter any number I want?

(I know this is a dumb usage considering the point of shields, but all the rest of my projects use shields.io badges keeping track of sourceforge download count so to maintain consistency I want this one to have the same badge.)

Answer (score 0):

My final solution was actually thanks to a helpful tutorial on [github](https://gist.github.com/afig/be5ab20c50062dba7cb835e30206659a#file-custombadges-md).

Shields lets you do multiple colors in one badge:

> Each badge has three main configuration options:
>
> 1. **Subject** - Text on the left side of the badge; the background color for this is normally gray (specifically, #555555)
> 2. **Status** - Text on the right side of the badge; usually the name of a service or a status code; the background color can be chosen by
>    modifying the next option
> 3. **Color** - The background color for the text on the right side of the badge; colors can be chosen by name, or by a given hex code (i.e.
>    #B7F5B2)

Putting this together in a string you can put any text you want for subject and status and then just change the color to make a download badge:

```
https://img.shields.io/badge/Downloads-10,000-green.svg
```

(Note: for multiword solutions you will need `%20` to represent a space)